# Parsing in PIG Bags and tuples

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

**Pig Code**

```
describe b ;   

b: {key: int,columns: {T: (alpha: chararray)}}

dump b ;

(3032,{({(name),(john),(1405416697822000)})})

(3031,{({(address),(bangalore),(1405416684062000)}),({(name),(Michael),(1405416690767000)})})
```

Now I would like to process this data and get out put as :

```
        name       address

3031    John       <null>

3032    Michael    bangalore
```

please guide how to proceed? I am new to PIG.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You might use BagToString on your tuples containing columns and use regular expressions to find out if it is name or address